# I'm trying to have a user input a boy name and/or girl name to check to see if its on the popular names list using visual C#

Tags: c#, list

..when the user enters in a name, boy and/or girl, my message prints to screen saying that the name does exist in the list and another message after saying that the name does not exist in the list. I've tried different ways with my if statements but it's just not working right for me. Does anyone have any idea where I'm messing up my code? Code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Chapter7_problem6_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void checkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader inputFile1 = File.OpenText("BoyNames.txt");
            StreamReader inputFile2 = File.OpenText("GirlNames.txt");

            // create new lists to store boys and girls names
            List<string> boysList = new List<string>();
            List<string> girlsList = new List<string>();
            
            // read boy names file and add to list
            while (!inputFile1.EndOfStream)
            {
                boysList.Add(inputFile1.ReadLine());
            }

            // read girl names file and add to list
            while (!inputFile2.EndOfStream)
            {
                girlsList.Add(inputFile2.ReadLine());
            }

            // close file
            inputFile2.Close();

            // call display answer method
            displayBoyAnswer(boysList);
            displayGirlAnswer(girlsList);
        }

        // method to validate users choice and display message
        private void displayBoyAnswer(List<string> list1)
        {
            int position1;
            position1 = list1.IndexOf(boyBox.Text);

            if (position1 != -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(boyBox.Text+ " is a popular name!");
            }
            if (position1 == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(boyBox.Text+ " is not a name on the popular names list.");
            }

        }

        private void displayGirlAnswer(List<string> list2)
        {
            int position2;
            position2 = list2.IndexOf(girlBox.Text);

            if (position2 != -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(girlBox.Text + " is a popular name!");
            }
            if (position2 == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(girlBox.Text + " is not a name on the popular names list");
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in this code is the user supposed to enter a name?

Comment: Inside the text box when the form runs

Comment: boyBox to enter in boys names and girlBox to enter in girls names

Comment: Can you give an example where the code is not _”working right for me”_? … The code appears to work as expected in my tests.

Comment: Whenever I used a name that was on the list in either boy or girl text boxes, if it was a name, it would tell me that it was, then another message came up saying that it wasn't

Comment: But the code is checking BOTH boy and girl names …. `displayBoyAnswer(boysList);` … `displayGirlAnswer(girlsList);` … maybe you need to have two buttons, one for checking boys and another for checking girls.

Comment: @JohnG I'm only using one button. I got it to work now. I thank you for trying to help me out.

Comment: I am glad you got it working. But I have to ask, if there is only “one” button… then “why” two text boxes for the user to input into? From a user’s perspective that is awkward. But this is not important. Good Luck.

Comment: It was just the problem that I was given. I'm in school so I gotta follow specs

Comment: So, let me get this right, the specs are using “two” lists, one with girl names, and another with boy names. The user types in a name and presses a button. The code checks BOTH lists and returns if the name is found in one of the lists? I am confident the teacher would allow you to use a single text box instead of two, which makes me wonder if you are fully articulating what the requirements are.

Comment: Create an application that reads the contents of the two files into
two separate arrays or Lists . The user should be able to enter
a boy’s name, a girl’s name, or both, and the application should
display messages indicating whether the names were among the
most popular. This is the problem I was given and it is a problem in the "Starting out with visual C#" book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- you have two textboxes, one for boy, one for girl. This is how you know the user wants to search the girl names for "Lee" and not the boy names (Lee is typically a unisex name)
- only one of the boxes will be filled in by the user (quite a dangerous assumption, btw)

You've written a lot of code that can be more succinctly expressed as:

```
bool popBoy = boyBox.Text != "" && File.ReadAllLines("boynames.txt").Contains(boyBox.Text);
bool popGirl = girlBox.Text != "" && File.ReadAllLines("girlnames.txt").Contains(girlBox.Text);

if(popBoy || popGirl)
  MessageBox.Show("it's a popular name");
else
  MessageBox.Show("it's not a popular name");
```

You can split it out differently if you want to be more informative (and remove the "only one box filled" restriction)

```
MessageBox.Show("it " + (popBoy?"is":"is not") + a popular boy name");
MessageBox.Show("it " + (popGirl?"is":"is not") + a popular girl name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You've copied and pasted what is functionally the exact same method to two functions, and then you execute both of them

```
displayBoyAnswer(boysList);
displayGirlAnswer(girlsList);
```

This is why you're getting two message boxes.

So the program first checks the boy name (`displayBoyAnswer(boysList);`), find it's either there and the user is alerted that "X is a popular name!" or it's not there and the user is alerted "X  is not a name on the popular names list."

Then the program checks the girl name (`displayGirlAnswer(girlsList);`), and does the exact same thing but for the girls name and list.

The only four circumstances that exist for this program are:

- `MessageBox.Show(boyBox.Text + " is a popular name!")` and then `MessageBox.Show(girlBox.Text + " is a popular name!")`
- `MessageBox.Show(boyBox.Text + " is not a name on the popular names list.")` and then `MessageBox.Show(girlBox.Text + " is a popular name!")`
- `MessageBox.Show(boyBox.Text + " is a popular name!")` and then `MessageBox.Show(girlBox.Text + " is not a name on the popular names list")`
- **`MessageBox.Show(boyBox.Text + " is not a name on the popular names list.")` and then `MessageBox.Show(girlBox.Text + " is not a name on the popular names list")`**

The one in bold is the one you described experiencing.

I don't fully comprehend what you're trying to accomplish so I can't even tell you if this needs to be fixed or not. But I can help you understand what's happening.

Change your functions to this:

```
// method to validate users choice and display message
private void displayBoyAnswer(List<string> list1)
{
    int position1;
    position1 = list1.IndexOf(boyBox.Text);

    if (position1 != -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(boyBox.Text+ " is a popular boy name!");
    }
    if (position1 == -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(boyBox.Text+ " is not a name on the popular boys names list.");
    }

}

private void displayGirlAnswer(List<string> list2)
{
    int position2;
    position2 = list2.IndexOf(girlBox.Text);

    if (position2 != -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(girlBox.Text + " is a popular girl name!");
    }
    if (position2 == -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(girlBox.Text + " is not a name on the popular girls names list");
    }
}
```

Then run the program. You will get two message boxes again but this time the message boxes will clarify that one is for the boys name list and the other is for the girls name list.